# Forecasting binary time series

Tags: time-series, lstm, data, forecasting, binary

I am working on the next event occurrence prediction task and the data is binary time series with 1 if the event occured and 0 if not. I want to predict whether the event will occur or not on the day right after the last day of train sample.

I already tried to use LSTM network but the results are bad.

Could you please recommend which model or NN architecture would be better to use?